# Laravel function not reading the $id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my web application I have added the cache method. But the problem is its not reading the specified $id which is passing in the function. So that its throwing error like :

**ErrorException: Undefined variable: id**

What to do if anyone suggest any answers will be helpful.

Here is the code ->

```
public function relatedstory($id)
    {
        $key = $id;

        $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey($key);

        return cache()->remember($cacheKey, Carbon::now()->addDay(1), function ()
        {
            $story = $this->_story->findOrFail($id);
            $tags = $story->tags->random(1)->pluck('tag_id');
            $storyIds = StoryTagItem::whereTagId($tags)->get()->random(4)->pluck('story_tag_id');
            $relatedStory = [];
            foreach($storyIds as $storyId)
            {
                array_push($relatedStory, $this->_story->findOrFail($storyId));
            }
            return StoryListResource::collection($relatedStory);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `function() use ($id)` to inject the `$id` to closure.

```php
return cache()->remember($cacheKey, Carbon::now()->addDay(1), function () use ($id)
        {
 ...
        });
```